# How can i use code for g-suite Auto Signature?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

Recently I'm using gsuite service for my domain mail. I created several alias mail for my team, such as admin@mydomain.com, editor@mydomain.com, sales@mydomain.com, etc. from mail>settings>accounts option I have selected **When replying to a message:** Reply from the same address the message was sent to (instead of Default Address https://prnt.sc/po3j3n).

Now, When I will send a mail to someone, in my signature will be auto changed as a sender (alias sender https://prnt.sc/po3fsp). Is it possible? If yes, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Look, because of my studies coming from the G Suite API, for my work at [Bybrand](http://www.bybrand.io), related to an email signature. I believe you will need to update the email signature on the main account, as well as the alias addresses. The G Suite, in this case, Gmail, considers alias addresses as independent accounts when sending the message.

In Gmail, when you click to send a new message, open the composer. When you choose the sender, which in your case will be an alias address, the email signature changes automatically.

[image]

In order not to change the email signature, I believe you will need to have an identical signature for all aliases.

For the update of an alias email account to work, you need to add the email in the user account, as seen in the image below. If you only add the alias address in the G Suite panel and don’t link it to a Gmail account, the updating process will show an error.